# nginx redirection from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a **WireMock** application running locally and exposed to http. And, I am able to access the wiremock server at `http://localhost:8090/user/test`
I am trying to use nginx to redirect https CLIENT call to backend wiremock http i.e. `http://localhost:8090/user/test`
I have tried with below `nginx.conf` settings, but it throws below error.

Error:

```
curl -X POST https://localhost

curl: (60) Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user
:
:
:
```

[image: nginx.conf]

Comment: Please do not post images of code. See the [how to ask help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. It should be posted to https://serverfault.com/, but make sure to comply with their [on-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) rules.